# Mass Assignment Insert in Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, mass-assignment

In Laravel 5.1 I'm using mass assignment for inserts. But i want to learn how to bulk insert with Eloquent.

I need to insert sold products in order process.

Here is my data for insert.

```
   foreach($cart['fields'] as $key => $product)
    {
        $orderDetailData[] = [
            'order_id'       => $orderData['order_id'],
            'product_id'     => $product['id'],
            'quantity'       => $product['total_quantity'],
            'price'          => floatval($product['wholesale_price']),
            'vat'            => $product['vat'],
            'vat_value'      => floatval($product['vat_value']),
            'discount_ratio' => $product['discount_ratio'],
            'discount'       => floatval($product['discount_value']),
            'total_amount'   => floatval($product['total_amount']),
        ];
    }
```

Here is my code for insert

```
(new OrderDetail)->create($orderDetailData);
```

I think this method doesn't support bulk insert.

In Laravel 5.1 Manuel i see this.

```
DB::table('table')->insert($orderDetailData);
```

What should i do for mass assignment for bulk insert ? Should i use previous one (DB facade)

Because i'm getting error (500 internal server error) with this code

```
(new OrderDetail)->create($orderDetailData);
```

Comment: What is the error says `500 internal server error`?

Comment: Why would you be worried about mass assignment when you are manually setting the fields? Mass assignment was a problem when people wanted to do something like `Model::create($request->all())`, not when they manually specified which field gets added.

Answer (score 0):

To insert/creae using mass-assignment you may declare an array in your `Eloquent` model like this one:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'order_id',
    'product_id',
    'quantity',
    'more fields names here...'
];
```

Defined field names will be inserted. Check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment) for more. Also you may use [forceCreate](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_forceCreate) method which allows mass-assignment.

Also, the `500 internal server error` is not obvious about the specific error so find it out.

Answer (score 0):

this is example you can make array of your data and can insert the same way here going on.

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'name'=>'Coder 1', 'rep'=>'4096',
        'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'modified_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
       ),
    array(
         'name'=>'Coder 2', 'rep'=>'2048',
         'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
         'modified_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
       ),
    //...
);

YourModelName::create($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can insert that way

```
$data = array(
array('name'=>'Coder 1', 'rep'=>'4096'),
array('name'=>'Coder 2', 'rep'=>'2048'),
//...
);
OrderDetail::insert($data);
```

also make fillable those fileds

```
protected $fillable = [
'name',
'rep_id',
];
```

Comment: i've already used fillable. But i don't know that i can call methods of OrderDetail model staticly.

Comment: @CihanKüsmez yes you can call staticly

Comment: can call every method of Models from Controllers staticly ?

Comment: @CihanKüsmez yes you can